# How to add customised content to Different cell content

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a `UITableVIew`. There are 3 rows and i want each row to have different cell content.

The first cell should have a LABEL, 2nd a LABEL a buttons and the 3rd cell should have 2 labels and a button. The following diagram illustrates how the table show up.

[image]

I was possible to adjust the height of the 3 cells with no issue, i used `heightForRowAtIndexPath` for this.

First i dragged the Label (from the first cell using storyboard to the .h file) to create an IBOutlet. Likewise i did for all the cell content that belonged to other cells as well.

I ended having the following error `The myButton outlet from the MyTableViewController to the UIButton is invalid. Outlets cannot be connected to repeating content.`

Can someone tell me how to add custom content for different cells using storyboard.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"c1"];

    UITableViewCell *cell1 = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"c2"];



//content for cell 1

cell.label1.text =@"hi";



//content for cell 2

cell1.label2.text =@"hi 2";
```

UPDATE

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    Cell1 *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell1"];

    Cell2 *cell1 = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell2"];


    if (cell == nil)

    {

        cell = [[Cell1 alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle

                                      reuseIdentifier:@"cell1"];

    }

        if (cell1 == nil) {

        cell1 =[[Cell2 alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle

                                        reuseIdentifier:@"cell2"];

    }

    cell1.la1.text= @"Hey Man";
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't create an outlet from the `UITableViewCell` to the `UITableViewController`. You need to create subclasses of `UITableViewCell`, set your prototype cell to be of that class type and then connect an outlet to this new cell class.

There can be many copies of a cell in a tableView, outlets have a 1 to 1 mapping. Trying to do this would break if you had more than 1 copy of that cell.

I would suggest taking a look at this link:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/50308/storyboards-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-1

There are 2 sections detailing how to create cells starting from "Designing Your Own Prototype Cells"

**Edit**

If your issue is when to create each cell you need to use the `indexPath` in the callback to work this out. Below is a sample. However this is completely unrelated to the question you've asked of how to use an IBOutlet on a cell.

```
if(indexPath.row == 1) 
{
    MyLabelCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"c1"];
    // customise cell
    return cell;
}
else if (indexPath.row == 2 || indexPath.row == 3)
{
    MyButtonCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"c2"];
    // customise cell
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: I created custom cells, but i am sure how to refer it from `cellforrowatindexpath`. Can you tell me how ?

Comment: @llep its explained in the tutorial I linked you to under `Using a Subclass for the Cell`

Comment: Yes i know how to do that. But, i am having 2 UITableVIewCell classes here. Please look at the updated code of my `cellforrowatindexpath`. The tutorial does not explain how to have 2 `UITableVIewCell`

Comment: @lllep i've edited my answer to show how to use the `indexPath` object that is returned in the callback. You need to learn to google these issues, there are thousands of tutorials for this stuff, thats how I learned Objective-c